# tricky method Overloading in java

Tags: java, overloading

```
class ABC {
    void doMe(String s) {
        System.out.println("String");
    }
}

class XYZ extends ABC {
    void doMe(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
}

public class StopStart  {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ABC o = new XYZ();
        o.doMe(null);
    }
}
```

What will happen and why?
string class extends Object. So which doMe() will execute.
Is it a compilation error?

Comment: String will be printed

Comment: Are you sure Murat? I would have expected "Object" to get printed. Isn't that how polymorphism works in Java? Edit: Nevermind, the methods have different signatures and aren't getting overridden

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson That's not how it works. He declared `o` as type of `ABC` - so it will use the method of `ABC`. Because the compiler does not know of the existence of `doMe` from the `XYZ` class or any other method from there, because it's not that type anyways.

Comment: My edit should have cleared that up. If the method signatures matched, the method of XYZ would have been called instead. Although we both know that this isn't the case.

Comment: @MuratK. Here's an executable example showing that the method in the subclass would be called in that scenario: [https://repl.it/FMlD/0](https://repl.it/FMlD/0)

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson This only applies to parameter less methods or methods with the identical signature. That's where the confusion happened.

Comment: I've updated it with parameters to show that it's still true. When I said "the same signature", I meant the same parameters too. Perhaps that's where the confusion started.

Answer (score 1):

Overloading is resolved in compile time, according to the compile time type of the variable `o`. Therefore doesn't matter which methods are defined in the `XYZ` sub-class. Only the methods of `ABC` are relevant.

Therefore only `void doMe(String s)` is considered by the compiler, and that's the chosen method.

Comment: If that was the reason, XYZ o = new XYZ() would print "Object". But it doesn't...

Comment: @GrishaWeintraub if the type of `o` was XYZ, there would be two candidates, and the candidate with the most specific type would win (i.e. `void doMe(String s)` would still be chosen), but that's irrelevant to the question that was asked, since in the posted question there is just one candidate.

Comment: You are right. +1